setting pipeline state as GST_STATE_NULL end with SIGSEGV
I want to stop getting a stream from a camera.
After I set the pipeline state to GST_STATE_NULL, I get a segmentation fault.
gst_element_set_state(streaming_pipeline_, GST_STATE_NULL);

In GDB, the segmentation fault occurs in the following block:
auto msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(streaming_pipeline_->bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
                                              static_cast<GstMessageType>(
                                              GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

GDB

This is a legacy codebase, and this part with gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered usually works correctly. Every time we receive GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS, we handle it appropriately and proceed with the next steps. The only problem arises when I attempt to change gst_element_set_state to GST_STATE_NULL (to handle SIGTERM)."

You may try sending EOS to the pipeline such as GstEvent*  event = gst_event_new_eos(); gst_element_send_event(pipeline, event);, then wait for the EOS message on the bus and only then setting pipeline to NULL.
